# Vector space, set that generates vector space

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

I have difficulties with this problem: $V$ is a set of all real matrices $2\times3$ such as that the sum of elements in the matrices is equal to zero. The set $V$ with addition and scalar multiplication creates a vector space $\mathbf V$. Find a five element set that generates vector space $\mathbf V$. Any ideas? Thank you very much

Comment: Are you talking about $2\times2$ matrices? And what have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to math.se, GorteX! You'll find you'll receive more (and better) answers when your question indicates your work so far, or at least what you've already tried.

Comment: Sorry, it is 2x3 matrices, well I have tried matrices, where one lement is 1 and second one in a different position is -1 but that didnt workout. I have tried to combine where the ones and minus ones are, but it never generated the whole vector space.

Comment: It does work out. You just need to show that any 2x3 matrix whose elements sum to zero can be written as a linear combination of such matrices.

Comment: forget about matrices. Think about vectors in six dimensions, with the property that their components sum to zero. It is the same, but I think it is easier!

Comment: Well, when I created the 5 element set where the matrices had one member equal to +1 and second one to -1, I have always managed to find a matrix, whose sum of elements equaled to zero, but I wasn´t able to find a linear combination of matrices from my set that would creat that matrix...

Comment: To get independence use the determinant!

Comment: @Lolman thx, I have tried that too, but again, when I took 5 six dimension vectors with one +1 and one -1 I came to conclusion that it doesn´t create the whole vector space

Comment: @GorteX it doesn't create the whole of $\Bbb R^{2\times 3}$, but it does create all of $V$.

Comment: once you get five independent vectors which satisfies a linear equation in a six dimensional space you get a set that generates all the elements that satisfy that equation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{v_1,\dots,v_5\}$ denote the matrices
$$
v_1 = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&-1}, v_2 = \pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&-1},\dots\\
v_5 = \pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&1&-1}
$$
Now, let $M \in V$ be given by
$$
M = \pmatrix{a&b&c\\d&e&f}
$$
since $M \in V$, we note that $a+b+c+d+e+f = 0 \implies f = -(a+b+c+d+e)$.  Now, show that we can write
$$
M = av_1 + bv_2 + cv_3 + dv_4 + ev_5
$$

Comment: I will try that :) that sounds very good :-)...and if I manage to prove that **M** can be written as the sum of av_1+b_v2+...+ev_5 that should be it, shouldn´t it? :-)

Comment: The last equation I can rewrite as sum of matrices \begin{pmatrix} a&0&0\\ 0&0&-a \end{pmatrix}+...+\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0\\0&e&-e \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} a&b&c\\d&e&-a-b-c-d-e \end{pmatrix} and because a,b,c,d,e are real numbers it creates the whole *V*? Am I right? Thx...P.S. I will try to make my LaTeX writing better :-)

Comment: Yes, that's right.  We know it creates all of $V$ because the only thing we knew about $M$ was that $M \in V$

Comment: and all of you guys thank you very much, really appreciate it...thx

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if the coefficients in five places are chosen arbitrarily, then the sixth coefficient is determined. Let the “sixth place” be the place $(2,3)$. For example, you have the matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
Can you find other four and determine they are a basis for your vector space?

Comment: So if I took your matrix lets call it matrix a) and then the rest of 4 matrices will look like the matrix a) but the +1 elemnt will be shifted one position to the right?

Comment: @GorteX Yes, that's the idea. Those matrices belong to $V$; are they a basis?

Comment: I would say they are a basis, beacause they are linearly independent

Comment: @GorteX They certainly are, but you have also to prove that any element in $V$ is a linear combination of them. Alternatively, you have to prove that the dimension of $V$ is at most $5$.